# Gradle build failed with exception: could not get resource. (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build an APK of my flutter app (which works on web) but I am getting problems with the gradle build. When I build it it throws this exception in the Messages

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':audioplayers'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':audioplayers:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :audioplayers
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom'.
               > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.19.174] failed: Read timed out
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':audioplayers' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':path_provider'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.













* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          100.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have checked my internet connection, upgraded my flutter, updated android studio plugins and gradle, and tried a few online solutions. I am still getting this and I am at a loss. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the build fails almost immediately after you run it no? More often than not the problem is usually in the pusbec.yaml file. Like 85% of the time. I can see an error of an unknown property 'android', you either implemented it wrongly or more likely mistyped the path.